# Free text field for zend certification test

Tags: php, zend-framework

So I am doing some practice tests on the phpriot page and notice something odd. There is this question that asks you what is the first row returned in a query. The query itself simply has something like this:

```
select u.name from users u .... order by u.name;
```

Anyway from the looks of it, the obvious answer is Fred in a series of name arranged in alphabetical order.

What I notice is that if I enter Fred, it says my answer is incorrect. Yet when I put in fred or FRED, it says my answer is correct.

Now the question is phpriot says they model after the real php test, so my question is on the REAL Zend Cert Test where you enter a free form text field, does casing matters? Suppose the answer is "Fred" but can you only enter "fred" or "FRED?"

Edit: Oh yeah here's something else that's odd. The question sometimes appear as a multiple choice radio button with "Fred" as one of the answers. When I select that, it says that I'm correct. Yet in the free text field version, it appears that "fred" is correct but "Fred" is incorrect even though that's how it appears on the sample data.

Just worried about the real test being something like this.

Comment: I had an issue with the similar question from the actual Zend test, where no ORDER BY clause was specified; but the question assumed a particular first row - that is never guaranteed by any database without an ORDER BY

Comment: However, this isn't using the Zend cert s/w, so it may be a simple oversight on the phpriot test s/w

Answer (score 0):

The real test won't be like that, that's for damn sure. But you will also not know your is correct or incorrect.

Just prepare and give the test.